How to get week number per month from Wednesday - Thursday on Power Bi?
I'm trying to count weeks per month: Thursday - Wednesday
I'm counting the following 4 weeks:
Week 1: Thursday: October 3 - Wednesday: October 9
Week 2: Thursday: October 10 - Wednesday: October 16
Week 3: Thursday: October 17 - Wednesday: October 23
Week 4: Thursday: October 24 - Wednesday: October 30

The formula im using only counts Sunday - Saturday
=
1 + WEEKNUM( 'ECR'[Date Originated] )
    - WEEKNUM( EOMONTH( 'ECR'[Date Originated], -1 ) + 1 )

How do I adjust this formula to fit the correct days?
Is there a different formula to use to count weeks from Thursday - Wednesday rather than Sunday to Saturday?

What about partial weeks? For example, January 2021 would have only three full weeks counting Thursday--Wednesday.

Try to shift the Date Originated to start the week on Thursday :
= 1 + WEEKNUM( 'ECR'[Date Originated] - 3 ) 
    - WEEKNUM( EOMONTH( 'ECR'[Date Originated], -1 ) - 2 )

